# Leading exponential order

Tags: reference-request

I found the following definition of equivalence to *leading exponential order* in the book

Mezard, Marc, and Andrea Montanari. *Information, physics, and computation*. Oxford University Press, 2009.

The definition is as follows:

> The notation $A_N \dot{=} B_N$ will be used throughout the book to
>   denote that two quantities $A_N$ and $B_N$ (which behave exponentially
>   in $N$) are equal to **leading exponential order**, meaning
>   $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} (1/N)\log(A_N/B_N) = 0$.

This is the first time I encounter this definition. Is it in common use somewhere else? Where can I study more about its properties?

Comment: That's a fairly standard term, it is a kind of weak asymptotic equivalence. There isn't really much to be said: $A_N$ and $B_N$ are $e^{N f(N)}$ and $e^{N g(N)}$ respectively, and $f(N)$ and $g(N)$ are asymptotically equivalent in the usual sense (i.e. with ratio tending to 1).

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Can you point to any additional references where this term is used? Ideally textbooks.

Comment: You can look into any source on large deviation theory; the same concept will be used but it may not be given the same name. I learned a lot from *Random Perturbations of Dynamical Systems* though this may have a different focus than you really want.

Comment: @Ian  I am reading about large deviation theory and I'm loving it. Very powerful methods. Sometimes you can't find the appropriate keyword to  find literature on a topic unless it is pointed out. Thanks a lot.